# How can I determine the most efficient number of grid columns and rows based on the number of items?

Tags: discrete-optimization, operations-research

I am developing a game that displays a grid of cards. Before the cards are rendered, I need to determine the layout of the grid. Given the number of cards, I need to find the number of columns and the number of rows that would be most space-efficient.

The cards being rendered are all of the same size and the maximum and minimum number of rows and columns will be $5$ and $3$, respectively. I am terrible at math, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So ...  ... if you have, say, 15 cards, you'd rather have a 3x5 grid than a 4x4 grid?  Is that what you mean by 'most efficient'?

Comment: Yeah i guess so lol

Comment: Well, with a min of 3 and a max of 5, there are not too many possibilities: for anything up to 9 use a 3x3, for 21 through 25 use a 5x5, and for any number of cards from 10 tp 20 you can figure it out by hand and handle it with a bunch of case statements.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum number of cards?